# How to make more than one listview respond for different onItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android

I'm using 4list views with class extending Activity. I have to perform different list item click function. Can i use the following method code for it? So how to set a single `onItemClickListener` for multiple `ListViews`?

```
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int index, long id)
   { 
       switch(view.getId())
       {
          case <listview1 Id> : //call method 1; break;

          case <listview2 Id> : //call method 2; break;

          case <listview3 Id> : //call method 3; break;
       }
   }
```

Comment: ya. But i m getting unexpectable output. If i click the 2nd list 's 1st item, i get the 1st list's 1st item.

Comment: Are you setting Listener for all the ListViews?

Comment: ya <listviewname>.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Comment: Hmmm post more code please? Have you called setId() on each of the views's correctly? _I think_ the default value is 0 and that they're not auto-generated, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set different adapters for different list views.
I take two list view for example. So take two adapter for these two. And setOnItemClick(context) will be like as below..

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adv, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(adv.getId()) {
        case R.id.ListView1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "list1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.ListView2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "list2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }

}
```