# Issue with two listsviews on android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have 2 ListView, and elements inside they list have a onClick event.

When I click on first element on line 1 it execute the onclick event of fist element of the second list.

```
//Adapter
mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);

//Lists/adapters/events
ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
pairedListView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);


ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

//Click Event
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {    
  Log.d(TAG, "element: "+ DeviceArrayList.get(arg2).getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: are the two listview are on same layout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make more than one listview respond for different onItemClickListener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580991/how-to-make-more-than-one-listview-respond-for-different-onitemclicklistener)

Comment: Yes, in the activity_main layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 different Listeners to handle click event to avoid this issue.

for device listview,

```
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {    
  Log.d(TAG, "element: "+ DeviceArrayList.get(arg2).getName());
  }
}
```

then

```
newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
```

for paired listview

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mPairedClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {    
  Log.d(TAG, "element: "+ SomeOtherArray.get(arg2).getName());
  }
}
```

then

```
pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mPairedClickListener );
```

One more way is, you can add logic to identify from which listview the click event is coming. As you are using same clicklistener, you should check from which listview the event is coming. Then you can pick corresponding ArrayList