# How to get tab name

Tags: android, listview

I am using slidingtablayout. There are 5 tabs and i am populating each of them with listview from different json requests. I need to get the name or the id of the tab on clicking on one of the items of the list view

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to supply us with your current code or implementation - that will give us some direction on how to help you.

But my first guess on your implementation: I am assuming when you say SlidingTabLayout you are referring to the code outlined on android developers: https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html#l199

If that is the case, you can get the tab name from the view pager when a tab is clicked and registered in the click listener:

```
private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    //Get tab name from mViewPager - differs based on your implementation
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any help on how to implement this

Answer (score 0):

Yes is that one outlined in the android developers
Ok, here is the situation

```
     @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

                View view=null;
                if(position == 0){
                   view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,container, false);
                    homeList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_list);
                    queryImp(view, "");
                   homeJSONAdapter = new JSONAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity().getLayoutInflater());

                    homeList.setAdapter(homeJSONAdapter);
                    homeList.setOnItemClickListener(this);


                }else{
                    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.other_pager_item,container, false);
                    otherList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.other_list);
                    queryImp(view, "other");
                    otherJSONAdapter = new JSONAdapterOther(getActivity(), getActivity().getLayoutInflater());

                    otherList.setAdapter(ekonomiaJSONAdapter);
                    otherList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

                }

                container.addView(view);

                view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);

                return view;
            }

this is the code that populates the tabs on SlidingTabsBasicFragment and the following is the onclick for the items of the lists

 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            if(position == 0)
            {

                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) homeJSONAdapter.getItem(position);
                String imageURL = jsonObject.optString("img_url");
                String artText = jsonObject.optJSONObject("content").optString("rendered");
                String artTitle = jsonObject.optJSONObject("title").optString("rendered");


                Intent detailIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleArticle.class);


                detailIntent.putExtra("imgURL", imageURL);
                detailIntent.putExtra("articleText", artText);
                detailIntent.putExtra("articleTitle", artTitle);

                startActivity(detailIntent);

            }else{


                JSONObject jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) otherJSONAdapter.getItem(position);
                String imageURL1 = jsonObject1.optString("img_url");
                String artText1 = jsonObject1.optJSONObject("content").optString("rendered");
                String artTitle1 = jsonObject1.optJSONObject("title").optString("rendered");

               y
                Intent detailIntent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleArticleOther.class);


                detailIntent1.putExtra("imgURL1", imageURL1);
                detailIntent1.putExtra("articleText1", artText1);
                detailIntent1.putExtra("articleTitle1", artTitle1);


                startActivity(detailIntent1);

            }
```

which basically, all it does is click on the item of the list and gets to the full article to read. For some reason it all gets a mess. (when i do a log on the position, it gets the position of the item of the list and not that of the tab) When i try to click on an item of the homeJsonAdapter it goes to the article of the otherJsonAdapter. I dont know why.
So what i want to do is get the name of the tab in which the listview is and based on that name, create the JsonAdapter and get the article

Comment: Any idea on how to implement this

Comment: its ok, i found the solution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580991/how-to-make-more-than-one-listview-respond-for-different-onitemclicklistener